Quarkus native image : Exe file is not generated
I am running 3.15.1 with GraalVM 21 on windows.
The build of native image finishes with no error, I have the runnable file generated but I cannot run it in Windows. I ran the same process with Quarkus 2 and GraalVM 17 a year ago and got an .exe file .
Why the .exe file is not generated ? Can I run native executable file to run without docker

Command line:
gradlew.bat build -Dquarkus.native.enabled=true -Dquarkus.package.jar.enabled=false -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args="--enable-preview"

Build Log:
jdk-21: Pulling from quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image
Digest: sha256:039ba92b94eb66e82e70a68de2ce483e6af43d84cfb7567a9cfa1b0792b71dc6
Status: Image is up to date for quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:jdk-21
quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:jdk-21

What's Next?
  1. Sign in to your Docker account ? docker login
  2. View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations ? docker scout quickview quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:jdk-21
========================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' (executable)...
========================================================================================================================
For detailed information and explanations on the build output, visit:
https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/BuildOutput.md
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                   (22.9s @ 0.26GB)
Java version: 21.0.5+11-LTS, vendor version: Mandrel-23.1.5.0-Final
Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3
C compiler: gcc (redhat, x86_64, 8.5.0)
Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
9 user-specific feature(s):
- com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
- io.quarkus.caffeine.runtime.graal.CacheConstructorsFeature
- io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase
- io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase for the [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] categories
- io.quarkus.jdbc.postgresql.runtime.graal.SQLXMLFeature
- io.quarkus.runner.Feature: Auto-generated class by Quarkus from the existing extensions
- io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature: Disables INFO logging during the analysis phase
- org.eclipse.angus.activation.nativeimage.AngusActivationFeature
- org.hibernate.graalvm.internal.GraalVMStaticFeature: Hibernate ORM's static reflection registrations for GraalVM
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 experimental option(s) unlocked:
- '-H:+AllowFoldMethods' (origin(s): command line)
- '-H:BuildOutputJSONFile' (origin(s): command line)
- '-H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature' (origin(s): command line)
- '-H:+GenerateBuildArtifactsFile' (origin(s): command line)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build resources:
- 3.56GB of memory (23.0% of 15.47GB system memory, set via '-Xmx4g')
- 16 thread(s) (100.0% of 16 available processor(s), determined at start)
04:43:55,159 INFO  [org.hib.orm.con.pooling] HHH10001005: Database info:
        Database JDBC URL [undefined/unknown]
        Database driver: undefined/unknown
        Database version: 12.0
        Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
        Isolation level: <unknown>
        Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
        Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown
[2/8] Performing analysis...  [******]                                                                  (96.6s @ 2.19GB)
   22,117 reachable types   (89.3% of   24,763 total)
   33,505 reachable fields  (56.3% of   59,509 total)
  120,740 reachable methods (58.1% of  207,692 total)
    6,984 types, 3,722 fields, and 11,459 methods registered for reflection
       62 types,    67 fields, and    55 methods registered for JNI access
       0 foreign downcalls registered
        4 native libraries: dl, pthread, rt, z
[3/8] Building universe...                                                                              (12.9s @ 2.54GB)
[4/8] Parsing methods...      [***]                                                                      (7.5s @ 1.26GB)
[5/8] Inlining methods...     [****]                                                                     (3.4s @ 1.64GB)
[6/8] Compiling methods...    [******]                                                                  (42.5s @ 1.91GB)
[7/8] Layouting methods...    [***]                                                                      (7.5s @ 2.56GB)
[8/8] Creating image...       [****]                                                                    (13.7s @ 1.99GB)
  47.05MB (44.37%) for code area:    82,832 compilation units
  58.60MB (55.26%) for image heap:  685,496 objects and 63 resources
406.01kB ( 0.37%) for other data
106.05MB in total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 10 origins of code area:                                Top 10 object types in image heap:
  13.54MB java.base                                           15.19MB byte[] for code metadata
   9.84MB org.hibernate.orm.hibernate-core-6.6.0.Final.jar     7.46MB byte[] for java.lang.String
   5.29MB code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar          5.66MB java.lang.Class
   1.94MB c.f.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar         5.02MB java.lang.String
   1.64MB org.postgresql.postgresql-42.7.4.jar                 1.87MB java.util.HashMap$Node
   1.54MB svm.jar (Native Image)                               1.86MB com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHubCompanion
934.71kB modified-io.vertx.vertx-core-4.5.10.jar              1.84MB java.lang.reflect.Method
905.06kB jdk.proxy4                                           1.60MB byte[] for reflection metadata
678.15kB o.jboss.narayana.jta.narayana-jta-7.0.2.Final.jar    1.48MB byte[] for general heap data
587.53kB com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.17.2.jar   1.25MB java.lang.Object[]
   9.61MB for 124 more packages                               15.38MB for 5185 more object types
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recommendations:
HEAP: Set max heap for improved and more predictable memory usage.
CPU:  Enable more CPU features with '-march=native' for improved performance.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       15.0s (7.1% of total time) in 736 GCs | Peak RSS: 4.02GB | CPU load: 8.63
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Produced artifacts:
/project/build-artifacts.json (build_info)
/project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner (executable)
/project/code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner-build-output-stats.json (build_info)
========================================================================================================================
Finished generating 'code-with-quarkus-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' in 3m 28s.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 12s
11 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 2 up-to-date




Seems clear from the first few lines of the output that you're using a builder image (as in, a container image) to build the native image (as in, a native executable). The container is a Linux container and includes a Linux version of native-image, which builds a Linux native executable. You need to use the Windows native-image, which builds a Windows native executable.
